# How do I Redirect on Https to another Https?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make a redirect from one domain to another. I want to redirect in all cases to "https://myweb.com" using htaccess file. Today I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myweb.com.ar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myweb.com.ar$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myweb.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Let's see the results:

1) http://www.myweb.com >> OK!

2) http://www.myweb.com.ar >> OK!

3) https://www.myweb.com.ar >> ERROR, The redirect is not happenning here.

What can I try to solve this issue?

Tks in advance!

Comment: You have a few issues with your host patterns... For example `^www.myweb.com.ar` should instead be `^www\.myweb\.com\.ar$`... That won't solve your actual question though, just mentioning...

Comment: Are you really sure that you are not looking at a cached result? Especially since you use 301 redirection code which _will_ get cached endlessly? In general it is a good idea to start with a 302 redirection and only change that to 301 once everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that is not a cached result. But I know you're right about the good practice of using a 302 first...

Comment: And _why_ are you sure it is not a cached result? The rules should work, so there must be another reason, that's why I ask. Your rules certainly can be enhanced, but they should work for the example you give.

Comment: but do you mean that the cache is from the server? Because it's not cached in my browser, that's for sure (I tried it on different places and devices).

Comment: Redirections are not cached on the server side, instead clients cache the redirection. If that is not the case here then you will need to start investigating what is going on. I suggest you start with taking a close look at your rewriting engine to understand what is going on step by step. For that enable rewrite logging in the http servers host configuration, then make a single request and examine the logged steps. You will find details about how to enable that logging in the http server documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rewrites, domain ar->com, http->https, www->non www, request->filename.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myweb\.com\.ar [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://myweb.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://myweb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myweb.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: The redirect doesn't work on https://myweb.com.ar BUT maybe is another issue because I get NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error. I think that the browser is checking first the SSL certificate without going to de htaccess file.